# Display Product collection issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection, product-list

I have a product collection and i have used below code to display in my template file as follows.

```
 <ol class="products list items product-items">
 <?php 
 $productCollectionSku = array('111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666'); // these are the comma separated skus.

        foreach($productCollectionSku as  $productSku){ 
            $product =  $block->getProductBySku($productSku);
            $productName = $product->getName();
            $shortDescription = $product->getshortDescription();
            $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
            $productId = $product->getId(); 

            $productPrice = $product->getPrice();   
            $addtoCartUrl = $block->getAddToCartUrlForProduct($productSku);
        ?>
        <li class="item product product-item">              
            <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                <a href="<?php echo $productUrl; ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                    <span class="product-image-wrapper">
                    <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" width="240" height="300" alt="<?php echo $productName; ?>"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="product details product-item-details">                      
                    <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                    <a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo $productUrl; ?>">
                        <?php echo $productName; ?></a>
                    </strong>                    
                    <div class="price-box price-final_price">
                        <span class="price-container price-final_price">
                            <span class="price-wrapper ">
                                <span class="price"><?php echo $productPrice; ?></span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </div>  
                    <form action="<?php echo $addtoCartUrl; ?>" method="post" class="best-items">   
                        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?php echo $productId; ?>">
                        <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">                        
                            <span>Add to Cart</span>
                        </button>
                    </form>                     
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ol>
```

Here is my getProductBysku function

```
  public function getProductBySku($sku)
   {
    return $this->productRepository->get($sku);// injecting this class in my block file \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,

   }
```

The above code working fine if all of the SKUs are simple products,

I need to prepare for **configurable products** also. Can we get the product info 
and display here config products with all the variations as swatches.

All I am looking here is how to display configurable products here exactly like in the category list page with the swatches being shown.

Where all the **color and size** swatches shows with clickable option.

Can anyone help me to implement this one?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What is not working / showing exactly? My guess is that only price and the toCartUrl is not working, can you confirm that?

Comment: @ArnoVandeCappelle, If any of the sku in array config product, I need to list that product with all combination selection like in default category list page. where color and size shown.

Comment: @ArnoVandeCappelle, Are you clear with it now?

Comment: Share your `$block->getProductBySku($productSku);` code

Comment: @ChiragPatel, I have updated the code

Comment: Do you want like get product's html part by product id which display in product listing page. Right?

Comment: Yes i need to display product in list way with config products..same like in category page

Comment: where you are getting above collection ? i.e CMS page Or CMS page Or Controller

Comment: In block file, i need to display collection in my template file

Comment: @Pawan,did you clear about my issue?

Comment: Try this `$product->getTypeId()=="configurable"` ?

Comment: @MohitRane, yes using this we can know whether its a config product, but i want the html for it to display like category page. Are u cleared with my question?

Comment: Is the collection coming from order or shipment by any chance? If you are getting the item, there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: @coderGeek,In my question i am loading product data with sku, $productCollectionSku = array('111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666'); looping each item and displaying there is no further collection, I am loading product object for each sku there

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ol class="products list items product-items">
     <?php 
     $productCollectionSku = array('111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666'); // these are the comma separated skus.

            foreach($productCollectionSku as  $productSku){ 
                $product =  $block->getProductBySku($productSku);
                $productName = $product->getName();
                $shortDescription = $product->getshortDescription();
                $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
                $productId = $product->getId(); 

                $productPrice = $product->getPrice();   
                $addtoCartUrl = $block->getAddToCartUrlForProduct($productSku);
            ?>
            <li class="item product product-item">              
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                    <a href="<?php echo $productUrl; ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <span class="product-image-wrapper">
                        <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" width="240" height="300" alt="<?php echo $productName; ?>"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">                      
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                        <a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo $productUrl; ?>">
                            <?php echo $productName; ?></a>
                        </strong>                    
                        <div class="price-box price-final_price">
                            <span class="price-container price-final_price">
                                <span class="price-wrapper ">
                                    <span class="price"><?php echo $productPrice; ?></span>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </div>  
                        <form action="<?php echo $addtoCartUrl; ?>" method="post" class="best-items">   
                            <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                            <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?php echo $productId; ?>">

$productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
$productTypeInstance->setStoreFilter($product->getStoreId(), $product);


if($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
$productTypeInstance = $_objectManager->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable');
$productAttributeOptions = $productTypeInstance->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $attribute):
$attributeId = $attribute["attribute_id"];
?>   
<div class="control">
    <span><?=$attribute["label"]?></span>
    <select name="super_attribute[<?=$attributeId?>]" id="select_<?=$attributeId?>" class=" required super-attribute-selectadmin__control-select" title="<?=$attribute["label"] ?>" aria-required="true">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <?php foreach ($attribute["options"] as $attrOption):?>
        <option value="<?=$attrOption["value"]?>" ><?= $attrOption["label"]?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>

<?php 
$customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
foreach ($customOptions as $option):
$optionId = $option->getOptionId();
?>
<div class="control">
<span><?=$option->getTitle()?></span>
    <select name="options[<?php echo $optionId?>]" id="select_<?php echo $optionId?>" class=" required product-custom-option admin__control-select" title="<?=$option->getTitle()?>" data-selector="options[<?php echo $optionId?>]" aria-required="true">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
<?php 
    foreach ($option->getValues() as $value) :
        $optionData = $value->getData();
        $optionTypeId = $optionData["option_type_id"];
        $optionPrice = $optionData["price"];
        $optionTitle = $optionData["title"]; 
 ?>
<option value="<?=$optionTypeId?>" price="<?= $optionPrice?>"><?= $optionTitle?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
        </div>
 <?php endforeach;?>

                            <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">                        
                                <span>Add to Cart</span>
                            </button>
                        </form>                     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ol>
```

Comment: hello @Sagar, can you please update me the code for swatches, i am looking for swatches to show over there

Answer (score 0):

**You can check `module-configurable-product`** in Magento

You can override `configurable.phtml` file to your module.

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

As i said in comments, you can check condition like this

`$product->getTypeId()=="configurable"`

and show your html according to the product.

**Hope It helps.**

Comment: hi @Mohit, is any chance to update as per my collection, I already have product object just need to display it, the above one is not complete answer..

Comment: hello @Mohit, can you please brief me how can i use your answer as per my requirement?

Comment: I need to show swatches there, the approach u given is for drop downs, Also pls brief me your answer..

Comment: you can check in default magento to see how it's working in core magento

**/var/www/html/magento_226/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/layout**

also check the `module-catalog` module

Comment: yes i checked over there, that module is for showing option in dropdown but in my case i am using swatches. What code i need to use to make it work like default list page

Comment: refer this link if that's relevant to you **https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-swatches-in-magento-2.html**

Comment: No it is not related to my question, I hope you are not cleared with my question, I have a product object which is configurable product I need to display that product in my custom template file like swatches, name, image,price and etc..

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below code to do, get configurable products collection with options.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$repository = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$product = $repository->getById('67');

$data = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableOptions($product);

$options = array();

foreach($data as $attr){
  foreach($attr as $p){
    $options[$p['sku']][$p['attribute_code']] = $p['option_title'];
  }
}


foreach($options as $sku =>$d){
  $pr = $repository->get($sku);
  foreach($d as $k => $v)
    echo $k.' - '.$v.' ';
  echo ' : '.$pr->getPrice()."\n";
}
```

Comment: hello, @Anas, yes above code will give the options that' fine, if you look into my code that will list collection with all info, same like how can i display in the same template, I am looking exactly for that, I need to fetch all option info if there is config product and display that like in category page, Pls dont share how to get the option info and all, that i can get it. Thanks. Help me to display the config product exactly like in category page, This is what i am looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Try following way...

**Create an extension simple and my code add in your helper file after you can get all data in phtml file**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $productCollection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $productIds = [1,2,3,4];
        $collection = $this->productCollection->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addFieldToFilter(
            'entity_id',
            ['in' => $productIds]
        );

        // sort categories by some value
        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }

        // select certain number of categories
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize); 
        }    

        return $collection;

    }
}
```

Comment: helllo @Rakesh, My question is to display the collection not to get the collection. Already i have collection just i need to display like product list as same like category page

Comment: yes but you can add your product id in my collection after you can showing products like listing page

Comment: yes, pls share the code to display collection like category page

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to inject a `\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable` in to your block file (which is responsible for rendering the image/label variations of a product). You can then, in your `AbstractBlock::_toHtml()` function add something like so:

```
$this->configurable->setProduct($this->getProductBySku('my-sku');
$this->setChild('swatches', $this->configurable);
return parent::_toHtml();
```

You can then output the data of `swatches` in your template by using `<?= $block->getChildHtml('swatches'); ?>`

Comment: hello @Adam, this i got the idea about this, but of you could update to my question that will be a great help, is it possible to update to my question with the code i used there.

Comment: hello @Adam, can you please elaborate?